# When using TestNG with IDEA and Gradle, the TestNG library and the test sources are not recognised, resulting in the tests not being run

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, code-completion

I have the following `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        picocli = '4.3.2'
        janino = '3.1.2'
        questdb = '5.0.1'
        babl = '0.4.1'
        pac4j = '4.0.2'
        eclipse_collections = '10.2.0'
        logback = '1.2.3'
        junit = '4.12'
        testng = '7.1.0'
        kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version "$kotlin_version"
}

apply from: 'activej.gradle'
apply from: 'pac4j.gradle'
apply from: 'kotlin.gradle'

description '...'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        withJava()
    }
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        apiVersion = '1.3'
        languageVersion = '1.3'
    }
}

test {
    // enable TestNG support (default is JUnit)
    useTestNG()

    // show standard out and standard error of the test JVM(s) on the console
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    // Fail the 'test' task on the first test failure
    failFast = false

    //we want display the following test events
    testLogging {
        events "PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'info.picocli', name: 'picocli', version: "$picocli"

    implementation group: 'org.codehaus.janino', name: 'janino', version: "$janino"

    implementation group: 'org.questdb', name: 'core', version: "$questdb"

    implementation group: 'com.aitusoftware', name: 'babl', version: "$babl", ext: 'pom'

    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.collections', name: 'eclipse-collections-api', version: "$eclipse_collections"
    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.collections', name: 'eclipse-collections', version: "$eclipse_collections"

    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: "$logback"

    // testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: "$junit"

    testImplementation group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: "$testng"
}
```

Files `activej.gradle`, `pac4j.gradle` and `kotlin.gradle has just other depedecies.

My directory structure is:

```
src
 |- main
      |- java
      |- kotlin
      |- resources
 |- test
      |- java
      |- kotlin
      |- resources
```

I am using TestNG.

I have a mock test file for the time being:

```kotlin
package com.sirinath.activej.config

import org.testng.annotations.*;

@Test
class TestRouteBuilder {
    @Test
    public fun test() {
        System.out.println("Testing")
    }
}
```

When I execute `testClasses` I get:

```
11:08:29 pm: Executing task 'testClasses'...


> Configure project :server
Kotlin Multiplatform Projects are an experimental feature.

> Task :wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

> Configure project :server
Kotlin Multiplatform Projects are an experimental feature.

> Task :server:compileKotlinJvm NO-SOURCE
> Task :server:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :server:jvmProcessResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :server:processResources SKIPPED
> Task :server:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :server:jvmMainClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :server:compileTestKotlinJvm NO-SOURCE
> Task :server:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :server:jvmTestProcessResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :server:processTestResources SKIPPED
> Task :server:testClasses UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 947ms
11:08:32 pm: Task execution finished 'testClasses'.
```

I have 3 issues here:

1. The tests are not run.
2. It says `NO-SOURCE` when I have code in `src\main\java`, `src\main\kotlin` and `src\test\kotlin` directories. If it is not finding the source I want to know where it is looking as there are source files.
3. IntelliJ IDEA IntelliSense does not recognise `org.testng.*` packages, as well as, other dependencies, though it is shown in the project structure in IDEA. I have tried clearing the IDE cache which has no effect.

Comment: Are the tests run if you run them with IntelliJ IDEA, not the gradle?

Comment: I tried both IDEA and command like. TestNG is how in the classpath in IDEA but still non of the annotation of packages are accessible through code completion. Also, they are marked as errors in the IDE. But when running not errors are thrown. Just the tests are not run. Does not seem to find the source for code, tests and resource even when in the standard locations as Gradle prints `NO-SOURCE`. This might be the reason the tests are not run.

Comment: What I meant is I have tried with Gradle on both the command line and the IDE.

Comment: What if you run them with TestNG run configuration created by IDE?

Comment: I am not sure if IDEA creates a TestNG configuration for Gradle projects.

Comment: @OlgaKlisho I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Changing `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version "$kotlin_version"` to `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "$kotlin_version"` and
2. removing

```
kotlin {
    jvm {
        withJava()
    }
}
```

solves all 3 problems.